# Joining xy points to regions to enable time slider-sensitive counts

Tags: arcmap, spatial-join, timeslider

I'm attempting to create a heatmap that responds to the time slider.

I'm working with historical newspapers. In one table, I have individual newspapers with fields for their years of publication and location. Another table has polygons representing regions of Colorado.

I have joined the points into the regions and created static heatmaps for the regions, but they show the cumulative total for the entire era; moving time slider doesn't change the map, because the join only counts the total for each region (that is, it isn't dynamically counting the total for the year selected by the slider).